# Salted hash algorithm

Tags: c#

I am using salted hash algorithm to secure the password. RNGCryptoServiceProvider is used to create the salt. Is it possible to create salt based on the user name? Please help me

Comment: here is a lib for this: http://encrypto.codeplex.com/, you could look into the source code if you want to learn how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You should first of all look into [what Salt is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) then you could revise [this greate code-chunk](http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx) to see how you use Cryptography with Salt in unfortunatly VB.

Now that you are familiar with how Salt works and have some knowledge of the C# implementation. You see that it actually is possible to do some modifications with the salting. For instance the computeHash takes a `byte[]` for salting, maybe you could try

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding  encoding=new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
encoding.GetBytes(str);
```

There is a world of possibilites for you, but to simply answer your question without spoiling the ending, yes, you can create a salt based on the username.